# Ambari 2.7.7 Build Failure

Tags: maven, ambari

I have issues with build Ambari Metrics Storm Sink (Legacy).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfOif.png)

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ambari-metrics-storm-sink-legacy: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-storm-sink-legacy:jar:2.7.7.0.0: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.storm:storm-core:jar:0.10.0.2.3.0.0-2557: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.storm:storm-core:jar:0.10.0.2.3.0.0-2557: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.storm:storm-core:pom:0.10.0.2.3.0.0-2557 from/to apache-hadoop (https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/): Failed to transfer file: https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/org/apache/storm/storm-core/0.10.0.2.3.0.0-2557/storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.0.0-2557.pom. Return code is: 502 , ReasonPhrase:Bad Gateway. -> [Help 1]
```

I have changed version storm core to 0.10.0 in pom.xml.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eY6TG.png)

But when building is appeared other error. Not found class IClusterReporter

Answer (score 1):

I believe `https://repo.hortonworks.com` no longer exists, based on the error "Bad Gateway". (At least, it didn't for a while, and was put behind a paywall from Cloudera). You would want to remove any references to it, which may mean that you cannot install Storm components any longer into Ambari. (Besides, you should disable "Legacy" components, anyway).

However, I do see this open PR - https://github.com/apache/ambari/pull/3686